# PHP MSSQL Query Syntax Error

Tags: php, sql-server, syntax

I'm having trouble with a syntax error in my mssql_query function. After a while of trying different things, I thought I'd bring it here. Thanks for any help.

This is the code:

```
<?php
...
$name = $_POST['name'];
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$contacttitle = $_POST['contacttitle'];
$streetaddress = $_POST['streetaddress'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$director = $_POST['director'];
$affiliation1 = $_POST['affiliation1'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$phone1 = $_POST['phone1'];
$affiliation2 = $_POST['affiliation2'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
$affiliation3 = $_POST['affiliation3'];
$address3 = $_POST['address3'];
$phone3 = $_POST['phone3'];
$yearsoperational = $_POST['yearsoperational'];
$donorsannually = $_POST['donorsannually'];
$limit = $_POST['limit'];
$coveraget = $_POST['coverage'];
$donors1 = $_POST['donors1'];
$claims1 = $_POST['claims1'];
$medexppaid1 = $_POST['medexppaid1'];
$donors2 = $_POST['donors2'];
$claims2 = $_POST['claims2'];
$medexppaid2 = $_POST['medexppaid2'];
$donors3 = $_POST['donors3'];
$claims3 = $_POST['claims3'];
$medexppaid3 = $_POST['medexppaid3'];
$donorinstructions = $_POST['donorinstructions'];

//Connect to MSSQL Server
$myServer = ".\MSSQLSERVER2008";
$myUser = "user";
$myPass = "password";
$myDB = "database,name"; 

//connection to the server
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

  //select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//insert form results into database
$query = mssql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (Name_of_Center,Name,Title,Street_Address,City,State,Zipcode,Phone,Fax,Email,Director,HA1,HA1_Address,
HA1_Phone,HA2,HA2_Address,HA2_Phone,HA3,HA3_Address,HA3_Phone,No_of_Years_Operational,Donors_Annually,Limit,Coverage,
Donors_2012,Donors_2011,Donors_2010,Claims_2012,Claims_2011,Claims_2010,Med_Exp_Paid_2012,Med_Exp_Paid_2011,Med_Exp_Paid_2010,Donor_Instructions)
VALUES ($name,$contactname,$contacttitle,$streetaddress,$city,$state,$zipcode,$telephone,$fax,$email,$director,$affiliation1,$address1,$phone1,$affiliation2,
$address2,$phone2,$affiliation3,$address3,$phone3,$yearsoperational,$donorsannually,$limit,$coverage,$donors1,$claims1,$medexppaid1,$donors2,$claims2,$medexppaid2,
$donors3,$claims3,$medexppaid3,$donorinstructions);");
if(!$query){
echo 'Failed to receive data. Please try again, or contact support';
}
else{
echo 'Successfully received data.';
$results = mysql_query($query);
var_dump($results);
}

mssql_close()
?>
```

The line it's saying has the syntax error is this:

```
$donors3,$claims3,$medexppaid3,$donorinstructions);");
```

Here's the error in browser:

[image]

```
Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Incorrect syntax near ','. (severity 15)
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com). You need to update it to use prepared statements to prevent your website from being hacked.

Comment: I was hoping to do so once I have all the functionality done, unless it makes more sense to do it now. I just haven't looked into it, so I assumed it would be time consuming, and I'm on a deadline to have the code functioning first.

Comment: deadlines are NEVER an excuse for writing miserably bad insecure code. Whatever crap you write now will just get thrown back in your face when it hits the fan later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **ENTIRE** problem is that you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). If you were aware of the problem, you'd also realize why your query has these syntax errors and is fundamentally broken: you forgot to quote **EVERY SINGLE** bit of data you're inserting into the query.

A quick dirty fix that really doesn't fix the fundamental problem:

```
VALUES ('$name','$contactname','$contacttitle',etc...
        ^-----^-^--- insert quotes everywhere.
```